# Running remote stored procedure with DDL locally

Tags: stored-procedures, linked-server, sql-server-2017, azure

Sorry if my question is redundant, I searched Stack Exchange and the internet for hours but do not have a definitive answer to my question.

Database: SQL Server 2017 + Azure

The goal is to build a BI infrastructure

I have multiple (20+) database servers (clients) which all have one common database in the cloud (Azure). All these clients should be exactly the same when these are on the same DB version. To make life easier when doing an update (almost weekly, tuning), I want my 20+ databases to update automatically.

I thought of the following solution:

- I create a table in the Azure DB which has the most recent client DB version (e.g. v1.2) **check**
- If I have an update script, I will put this as a stored procedure on the Azure DB. **check**
- I schedule a task on the client which checks the most recent client DB version once a day and compares whether an update is needed. **check**
- If yes -> run the "update": this is the stored procedure on the Azure DB which have to run on the client DB. **oh no**

Here I get into trouble, running the stored procedure which resides on the Azure DB obviously runs the stored procedure on the Azure DB. I don't know how I can run the stored procedure of the Azure DB on the client DB.

Motivation: I thought it would be clever to do it this way so I only have to change the content of the stored procedure and all clients would update itself when getting a connection with the Azure DB.

Also, is this the correct way of tackling this problem? Any help is much appreciated!

If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: What if you were to store the DML (script to create/alter stored procedures) in Azure also.  Then when it checks for an update, it could pull-down the DML and use OPENQUERY to run/process the DML.  Word of caution of course, OPENQUERY can also be used for evil, so be careful.

Comment: That could be a good idea. However, I have no clue on how I could pull-down the DML to create the SP on my clients. Any tips/ hints?

Comment: You store the DML as raw text in Azure. It sounds pretty abstract to use a DB to store raw SQL to be executed on another server, but that is the strategy.  @Hodgin made an example (below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to Azure to verify this all works without tweaking, but here is something you can try.

Here is some information on creating a linked server to Azure that might help you - I have not tested that part - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41145784

On Azure, create the stored procedure that contains the commands you want to execute on each client machine.  My example simply creates a `TestUpdateTable` and inserts the current timestamp.  I'm sure your stored procedure would be much more involved.

```
drop procedure if exists [dbo].[UpdateClient];
go
create PROC [dbo].[UpdateClient]
AS
begin transaction
drop table if exists dbo.TestUpdateTable;
create table dbo.TestUpdateTable (TextCol varchar(max));
insert into dbo.TestUpdateTable(TextCol) 
    select convert(varchar(30),sysdatetime());
commit
```

In the following example, I'm using a linked server connection to a server I call `SqlCompare`.  I'm also referencing a database called `SCUTILITY` on that linked server.  This is where I put the central stored procedure.  This simulates what would be in Azure.

On each client machine, run the following dynamic TSQL

```
Declare @cmd nvarchar(max)

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.UpdateClient;

SET @cmd = (
        SELECT *
        FROM openquery(SqlCompare, 'exec(''use scutility;select object_definition(object_id(''''dbo.UpdateClient''''))'')')
        )

PRINT @cmd

EXEC (@cmd)
GO
```

The intent is to drop the existing *local* client `UpdateClient` stored procedure first.  Then retrieve the text definition of the Azure stored procedure by using `object_definition` and put the results in a variable (`@cmd`).  Issuing `EXEC (@cmd)` will create the *remote* stored procedure *locally* on each client.

Now, execute the `UpdateClient` stored procedure locally on the client machine.

`EXEC dbo.UpdateClient`

The *execution* of the `UpdateClient` stored procedure just created the table `TestUpdateTable` and populated it with the current timestamp.  Again, your stored procedure would be more involved.

Now, you could issue `select * from TestUpdateTable` on the client machine and you should get a result back

Answer (score 0):

It sounds good, but i don't believe SQL Azure supports linked servers. 
Have you thought of an SSIS package? We do a lot of work using those.
There is also this option:  https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-sync-azure-sql-databases-and-on-premises-databases-with-sql-data-sync/ which I have not tried.

I use the Azure SQL Elastic Jobs database, but it won't run jobs on an on-prem server, just the Azure database.